# MediaInfo output to stdout

Tags: stdout, mediainfo

I have used MediaInfo before to extract information in a shell script in CygWin.

#!/bin/bash
IFS=$'\n'; for file in $(ls *.mp3 */*.mp3 ); do count=`"C:/Program Files/MediaInfo/MediaInfo.exe" $file | grep "Bit rate mode" | grep "Variable" | wc -l`; if [ $count -gt 0 ]; then echo $file VBR; fi done

For some reason, it no longer outputs to stdout.  It displays the data in a window.  Is there some command line flag tp force stdout?

Answer (score 1):

You use the Graphical Interface (GUI) version of MediaInfo, you need to use the Command Line Interface (CLI) version of MediaInfo.

See the different download options in the [MediaInfo Windows download page](https://mediaarea.net/MediaInfo/Download/Windows).